# What is the scope of Reflex Boosters' applicability (in terms of skills/action)?

Tags: fate, fate-core, eclipse-phase, transhumanitys-fate

The Stunt's effect description reads:

> You can activate reflex boosters to
>   gain a +2 to physical actions where
>   enhanced neural speed and reaction
>   time come into play.

What is that supposed to apply, and what is it not? Because if I take the description at face value, enhanced neural speed and reaction time is important in *a lot* of activities - at a minimum, all dodge rolls, most Fight rolls, the more action-heavy Pilot rolls, and arguably *some* of the Shoot rolls and who-goes-first resolutions.

Also, should 'activate' in Stunt descriptions generally be interpreted to mean it requires spending an action and/or a FP?

(For now I told my players to assume that Reflex Booster as described in the RAW is unavailable, and that they should negotiate a more specific bonus instead, at least until I figure out what it's scope can reasonably be.)

Answer (score 3):

### It's an appropriate scope for a Morph stunt.

It lines up with other Morph stunts, at least, which are equally broad: +2 to Rapport if it matters you're pretty, +2 to sneakin' if it matters you're a chameleon, +2 to understanding language, +2 to antivirus and consequence recovery, +2 to Athletics if you're gravity-connected, +2 to Athletics if you're *not* gravity-connected...

It shouldn't be read as requiring a Fate Point to activate because Morphs already have aspects to hit and the stunt costs you a Fate Point in the first place, and of the activatable Morph stunts, only the one that lets you teamwork with yourself mentions that it costs a Fate Point to activate.

Do note: "for a Morph stunt". A stunt linked to a morph, which you spend Refresh and probably resources on in the first place, which goes away when the morph does, which is technically portable to another morph but at a GM Fiat level of imposed expenses. And while not all Morphs cost Refresh in the first place, as far as I can remember all the combat forms, sports cars, and 1337 h4XX0rs that have Reflex Boosters do. (Also that last definitely argues for a liberal interpretation of the stunt because it's not a physical form.)  Because of the investment in and fragility of Morphs (at least as compared to characters) **it's not intended that Morph stunts should transfer over to being general-access character stunts in any other Fate campaign setting**.

But they do fit the nature of Morphs in Eclipse Phase, which are specialized bodies built for purpose - sink Refresh into a combat form's ability to be good at combat (or nail-biting action in general) and it will be a tier above the rank-and-file at it. That's why most opposition that's intended to be in a combat form has that Morph stunt - they will stomp you in zwee-fighting unless your Morph has it too, in which case you'll be back to punching and kicking on-level.